# Well-definedness of translation functor

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Fix $\eta, \nu \in \mathfrak{h}^*$ and write
$pr_\eta$ and $pr_\nu$ for the natural projections of the category $\mathcal{O}$ onto $\mathcal{O}_{\chi_\eta}$ and $\mathcal{O}_{\chi_\nu}$. If $L$ is finite
dimensional and $M \in \mathcal{O}$, then $M \mapsto pr_
\nu \left(L \otimes (pr_\eta M)\right)$ followed by inclusion into $\mathcal{O}$ defines an exact functor $\mathcal{O} \to \mathcal{O}$. 
Its restriction to $\mathcal{O}_{\chi_\eta}$ (without the inclusion) relates  the two subcategories $\mathcal{O}_{\chi_\eta}$ and $\mathcal{O}_{\chi_\nu}$. 
Write $T^\nu_\eta$ for the resulting functor
on $\mathcal{O}$ (or on $\mathcal{O}_{\chi_\eta}$). We call $T^\nu_\eta$ a translation functor.

**My question:** The definition of a translation functor $T^\nu_\eta$ depends on the choice of a finite dimensional module $L$, how to show it is well-defined?

Comment: I think you’re missing conditions on $L$, otherwise the functor you describe is clearly not independent of $L$. I think $L$ should be a highest weight module of highest weight $\nu-\eta$?

Answer (score 2):

Jantzen first defined translation functors around 1977, using a definite finite dimensional module, in 2.10 of his Habilitationsschrift [here](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=552943).    Note that at around the same time, Gregg Zuckerman was also considering tensor products with finite dimensional modules in the Lie group representation framework [here](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0457636).  The ideas in both constructions are similar but independent, and the use of a finite dimensional representation is quite specific.

Chapter 7 of my 2008 AMS textbook (with corrections!) follows the same pattern.    But note that the Jantzen idea of crossing walls does require a choice of weight in the wall involved: see 7.15 in my book.   This seems to need input from Jantzen's student Soergel, which still leaves an open question as to methodology:   Is there a simpler method of wall-crossing?